# ¿Como modificar el correo de cambio de contraseña hecho con auth de Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

En **Laravel Framework 5.4.18** ejecuté `php artisan make:auth`

Cuando solicito restablecer mi contraseña, recibo un correo electrónico que dice

(...)

> You are receiving this email because we received a password reset
>   request for your account

(...)

Quiero modificarlo completamente.

Comment: Checa estar rutas: vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Notifications\resources\views\email.blade.php vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword.php

Answer (score 1):

Ese mensaje funciona con notificaciones, por lo cual dependiendo de lo que quieras modificar exactamente, deberás crear una nueva notificación con artisan, y luego utilizarla en el modelo User, sobreescribiendo el método adecuado, de la siguiente manera:

```
/**
 * Send the password reset notification.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

En el archivo de la notificación respectiva la configuras como quieras, según lo establece Laravel en su documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#mail-notifications

En caso que desees cambiar el template general de las notificaciones, deberás publicar las vistas con artisan: `php artisan vendor:publish`

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta el siguiente comando:

`php artisan vendor:publish`

Luego podrás editar el template de **reset_password.blade.php** en la ruta **resources/views/vendor/notifications**